# My divs are not aligned properly

Tags: css, html, alignment

Here is a link of what I currently have for my skeleton design.

[image]
I'm new to using divs, I always used table but moving towards divs.
But anyways, my question would be...How do I align my content of each div properly.
I want the navigation to be centered along with the main content.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>

<title>Chomas Tool</title>

<meta charset="windows-1252">
<meta name="Keywords" content="chomas,tool,pinconning,michigan,machine,shop" />
<meta name="Description" content="Chomas Tools- description" />
<!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" /> -->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">
<div id="logo">
<img src="images/logo.gif" width="270" height="100" alt="Chomas Tool"></div>
</div><!-- Close header-->

<div id="navbox">Home | About | Projects | Contact</div>

<div id="content">TEST</div>

<div id="footer">Copyright &copy; Chomas Tool</div>


</div><!--Close_wrapper-->

</body>
```

Main.css

```
body {
background-color:#b0c4de;
}
p {
background-color:#e0ffff;
}
#wrapper {
height: 100%;
width: 900px;
border: 1px solid #000;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
#header {
background-color:grey;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
}
#logo {
height: 400px;
width: 300px;
float: left;
}
#search {
width: 350px;
height: 400px;
float: right;
}
#search table {
border: 0px solid #000;
padding: 0px;
}
#navbox {
background-color:darkgrey;
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
text-align:center
}
#content {
background-color:lightgrey;
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
}
#footer {
background-color:grey;
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: *"I always used table but moving towards divs."* - what rock have you been living under? The rest of the world already moved on to more semantic HTML5, using `<nav>` instead of `<div id="nav">`, and `<header>`, and `<footer>` etc.

Comment: Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WASEH/

Comment: just try text-align: center; in your #navbox?

Comment: Also, *"How do I align my content of each div properly."* we do not know what "properly" means to you if we don't know what you want to achieve. I do know you shouldn't be using fixed width and height rules for all your divs. Go with the flow....

Comment: Well its ok if you only use table(maybe you coded emails?)...Glad you are opening your coding methods.

Comment: @Niels Keurentjes, my main goal is just to center the navigation/content/footer so that there all all thing the middle of the page, and porportional in css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting strange results with that layout is that your #logo div is set to a height of 400px. That is pushing everything else over to the right.

If you remove the `height: 400px` on the `#logo` div, and then add this to your styles:

```
img {vertical-align: bottom;}
```

everything will appear as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code.

The reason your Nav div, Content div and Footer divs are aligning improperly is because you have your `#logo` div set to a 400px height and floated, but you aren't clearing your float.  Unfortunately you can't properly clear that div because you have a height on header of 100px, which is less than your 400px div that is nested inside the header.

For the purpose of teaching you, I'll assume your logo should NOT be 400px high, so I'll set it to be equal to the header height of 100px.

```
#logo {
height: 100px;
width: 300px;
float: left;
}
```

While we are on the concept of height, it's acceptable to have a fixed height on your header, as it's a div that shouldn't be super tall or allowed to change (generally speaking there are exceptions).  That said...  Your content div really shouldn't have a height, I can see you did it here to simulate that you had more content, instead let's just add some content there.

So now we are here: http://jsfiddle.net/dkCZ6/

As you can see the navigation is centered nicely, your content is where it should be as well as the footer.

Let's center the footer to make it nice looking...  I added `text-align: center;`

http://jsfiddle.net/dkCZ6/1/

```
#footer {
background-color:grey;
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Noticed that white space that was created between the nav and content area?  That's from adding the paragraph around the content stuff.  Let's reset all padding and margin by adding * { margin: 0; padding: 0; } to the top of our CSS.  (you should use a proper Reset CSS Stylesheet or use a [Normalize CSS Sheet](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).  These reset stylesheets help standardize elements across the different browsers, and also gives you a blank slate from which to develope from, without having to worry about weird things occuring, like that white space that we fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best answer I have:

```
text-align: center
```

But base on that code you have then I have done:

```
**margin: 0 auto**
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/WASEH/5/

Just to chow you I did this only on the **nav**:

Added:

```
 <div class="inner">Home | About | Projects | Contact</div>
```

and on CSS:

```
.inner {margin: 0 auto; width: 50%;}
```

Classes are always good to use when you want to do multiple calls of the same to minimize code. Get in the habit of doing classes.

Lastly I suggest learning HTML5...Divs are great but you can simplified your code with html5

..
..Its simple to learn :)

Comment: You've completely mis-diagnosed what the issue is, it was the fact the logo styling was pushing everything it out of alignment

Comment: YEah I saw that fix, but I saw his statement: "I want the navigation to be centered along with the main content." so the fix on the image did not resolve the centering...

Answer (score 0):

Add 

`<div style="clear:both;"></div>`
 after you close the header

Your image style is all wrong hence why everything will look in the wrong position.

You should also be aware that you can use 
margin: 0 auto; 
Rather than
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;

Consider using list elements for your navigation rather than just static text.